# C++ - How to use template typedef workaround in declaration of function?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I would like to use a templated typedef in various places, among other things in the declaration of an itself templated function. 
Here's my current attempt

```
template<typename T>
struct type{ typedef std::vector<T> sometype; }

template<typename TT>
void someFunction( type<TT>::sometype& myArg );
```

(Note that the `std::vector<T>` is merely an example). This does not work and gives a compiler error "template declaration of 'void someFunction'". I've already figured out that I need to put a `typename` in front of `type<TT>`, i.e.

```
template<typename TT>
void someFunction( typename type<TT>::sometype& myArg );
```

works. But this solution is - to say the least - a bit bulky. Are there alternatives?

Comment: This solution is perfectly fine and workable :-)

Comment: The only alternative is true template typedefs, which exist in C++11.

Comment: @KerrekSB: He is asking for a more elegant version. He already said that it is working like it is.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes could you point me to the syntax of the C++11 solution? I'm currently using either gcc 4.4 or 4.6 (and other people working on the code might even use other compilers) so this would probably something I would like to learn for future usage..
And yes, I'm looking for alternatives to the solution I've posted above.

Comment: If "sometype" meant "std::vector<T>," then wouldn't "type<TT>::sometype" mean "type<TT>::std::vector<TT>"?  Does the last even mean anything in C++?

Comment: I'm more worried about how to **use** the function. The compiler will not be able to deduce `TT` from `someFunction(vec)`.

Comment: @thb - `sometype` is a type definition inside `type` that resolves to `std::vector<T>` where `T` is the template parameter of `type`.  Thus `type<TT>::sometype` resolves to `std::vector<TT>`, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @BoPersson - if the compiler cannot deduce the correct type, you can always specify it: `someFunction<int>(vec);` -- `int` taking the place of `TT`

Comment: @Attila - That's clear now.  Thanks.

Comment: @BoPersson The intended use case is indeed, as Attila already mentioned, something like `someFunction<int>(vec)`

Comment: Those are only  supported in GCC 4.7 (soon to be released). It looks like `template <typename T> using type = std::vector<T>;` and then you can just use `type<T>`. It also doesn't prevent type deduction from working, like @BoPersson mentioned.

Comment: You cold use precompiler macros (but then why bother with templates...)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks. Would you like to put this into an answer? I think this would be useful..

Comment: *"GCC 4.7 (soon to be released)"*. **Very soon** it seems, like today :-)  [http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only is it bulky but it also prevents template parameter deduction:

```
std::vector<int> a;
someFunction(a); // error, cannot deduce 'TT'
someFunction<int>(a);
```

The alternative (in C++11) is template aliases:

```
template<typename T>
using sometype = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T>
void someFunction(sometype<T> &myArg );

std::vector<int> a;
someFunction(a);
```

You could also use a macro, except that macros are never the right answer.

```
#define sometype(T) std::vector<T>

template<typename T>
void someFunction( sometype(T) &myArg);
```

Also, I believe that your definition of sometype isn't valid pre-C++11. It should not have that typename:

```
template<typename T>
struct type{ typedef std::vector<T> sometype; };
```

I think C++11 changes the rule to allow it, but some C++03 compilers failed to correctly diagnose the issue.

Comment: AFAIK, `typename` is still "forbidden unless necessary" even in C++11. Could you add a note about how the version with template aliases doesn't prevent type deduction?

Comment: I think you are right about that `typename` business. I carelessly copied that part from one of my real typedefs which involves a typedef based on another (templated) typedef - and there the `typename` is obviously necessary.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I'm pretty sure it changed in C++11, but I don't have a good reference for it at the moment.